# cli commands for Billion 7402GX

Tags: command-line, port, forwarding, billion

hope I've come to the right place.
I have a Billion 7402GX which needs port forwarding done for CCTV.
I can't find the Virtual Server section in the web gui.
Is there a cli command I can use to show it again?
I know it should be there, I have seen it on another router.
Any advice would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about a CLI for it, but according to the WebUI emulator model on Billion's web page [for that model](http://www.billion.com/edu/3g/Demo-wireless-7402GX/), all your port forwarding settings are under:

`Advance -> Configuration -> Virtual Server`

[image]

That same site also offers the [User Manual](http://www.billion.com/support/download/usermanual/usermanual.html) if you want to go check if it (also) provides a CLI.

Comment: Thanks, downloading manual to have a look.
I tried going to the section you indicated, but it just isn't there :S

Comment: Had a look at the manual, and no luck. I've also been advised to upgrade the firmware incase the firmware was corrupt.
Also no go, I'm now trying the contact us page on the Billion website...